# Fastlane changelog_from_git_commits always empty when running to Github Workflow

Tags: github-actions, fastlane

Hi just wondering why the `changelog_from_git_commits` has a value when running to a local machine but when I tried to run my lane to Github Workflow.it always empty?

Fastfile

```
desc "Read changelog"
lane :read_commit_history do
  recent = changelog_from_git_commits(
    between: ["9025d4f", "HEAD"] # commit hashes
  )
end
```

Github Workflow

```
name: Read Changelog Workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Ruby 2.6
        uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.6.x
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: gem install bundler && bundle install && bundle update fastlane
      - name: Run Fastlane Compile Lane
        run: bundle exec fastlane read_commit_history
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Fetch all history for all tags and branches, just add the `fetch-depth: 0`.

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches